# Download boxfiles in a shared boxfolder using box developers app in java

Tags: java, download, box

We would like to use a remote shared box folder to download contained box files using java without having to establish oauth2 authentication with the provider of the shared folder.

It appears that even if the shared box folder is created with "People with the link" that a developer app, using this link, cannot download the content of the included box files without first establishing oauth2 authorization with the user supplying the link.

If anyone is aware of some functionality in a box developer app for doing this, would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question above.

A couple of partial solutions were found. Both solutions require some form of authorization action on the remote content source.

Instead of using a shared folder, the remote content source user can create a zip file of a folder to be downloaded, and saving the resulting zip in Box. In Box a shared link on the zip file can then be created and a shared link used for getting the folder content.

Another approach uses a box app with Authentication Method: App Token (Server Authentication). The remote content user uses the email address of the app from the app General Settings / Service Account ID to make the app a collaborator (editor works) on a folder that the app will download. The api authentication in the app (for us) is the Private key of the app. The download redirect urls generated in the app must be used immediately in the app. The expiration of the url is small.